# What does a Min Loser Tree with 11 players look like?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Basically I have to create a min loser tree with 11 players but I'm not entirely sure what it should look like. So far my best guess is:

```
                               W
                               |
                              L4
                        /           \
                  L3                      L3
              /      \                 /     \ 
           L2         L2             L2       P11          
        /   \         /   \         /\ 
      L1     L1     L1     L1     P9  P10
      /\     /\     /\     /\
    P1  P2 P3  P4 P5  P6 P7  P8
```

Sorry for the terrible ASCII representation, but I think you get the general idea. Is this visualization correct? I'm mostly concerned about the placement of the players.

I've searched the internet but all I get are results for bracketing software.

Answer (score 3):

i'm pretty sure that you already found the answer, but maybe someone else directed to this page would be happy to have it right under the question ...
in a loser tree, the parent of two child nodes is the loser of the two, the winner is further compared, so the tree should look like this (if we assume that the player with the min ID wins):

```
                 P1=W
                  |
                  P5
           (compare P1 to P5)
           /              \
        P3                  P7
 (compare P1 to P3)  (compare P5 to P7)
     /      \            /      \
   P2        P4        P6        P8
  / \       / \       / \       / \
P1   P2   P3   P4   P5   P6   P7   P8
```